# Grouping with OR in regex

Tags: java, regex

The below is my regex pattern. I am using this to validate an email address.

```
^[\\w]+(\\.|\\_)?[\\w]+\\@{1}[\\w]+\\.{1}(([A-Za-z]+)|(\\.{1}[A-Za-z]+))$
```

The email ID must follow the following rules .
1. Contains any number of alphabets or numbers before 1 period or underscore.
2. Followed by any number of alphabets or numbers before 1 @.
3. Followed by any number of alphabets or numbers before 1 period.
4. (Followed by any number of alphabets) or (1 period and any number of alphabets).

I am facing an issue with the 4th rule. It works fine for a email ID ending with @xyz.abc, but fails for @xyz.abc.ab

Is it not possible to group patterns for the fourth rule as I have done ?

Solution :

```
"^[A-Za-z0-9]+[\\._][A-Za-z0-9]+@[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:\\.[A-Za-z]+){1,2}$"
```

Comment: Modify rule 4 to say "Followed by any number of groups of periods followed by alphabet" which is equivalent to the original requirement but is easier to write regex for. I have included the right regex in my answer below.

Comment: It is possible to group patterns for the fourth rule as you have done but the resulting regex will be ugly. Both the answers below have simpler regexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description, what you want is actually:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]+[\\._][A-Za-z0-9]+@[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:\\.[A-Za-z]+)+$
```

Splitting this out, you have:

1. Alphas or numbers (`[A-Za-z0-9]+`)
2. Underscore or period (`[\\._]`)
3. Alphas or numbers (`[A-Za-z0-9]+`)
4. At sign (`@`)
5. Alphas or numbers (`[A-Za-z0-9]+`)
6. One or more of period plus alphas (`(?:\\.[A-Za-z]+)+`)

Note that `\\w` contains _, so you can't use it here.

Comment: This doesn't satisfy rule 3 which allows letters or numbers before the period and after the @ sign.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that \\w contains _. I had to replace the last + with {1,2} to limit the occurrence to 2 times. I have posted the answer along with my question. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
^[\\w]+(\\.|\\_)?[\\w]+\\@{1}[\\w]+(\\.{1}[\\w]+)+$
```

I should also point out that the actual regex for email is pretty complex. I hope you are not using it for any real checks on a website.

Comment: Does this satisfy your requirement? There was a syntax error in the regex which I have corrected in the update.

Comment: As pointed out by Russell, \\w allows underscores. I have posted the solution. THank you for the help.

Comment: You can short your regex to : `^\\w+(\\.)?\\w+@\\w+(\\.\\w+)+$`